# Convert varchar to numeric in mysql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric number.

I need to convert Indian comma format in values and store in the database.

```
SET @mainamount=(SELECT Isnull(Format(Cast(Sum(receipt_amount) 
AS MONEY), 'N', 'en-in'), 0) AS amount 
FROM   tbl_fee_receiptmaster 
WHERE  org_id = @org_Id 
AND academic_id = @academic_Id 
AND student_id = @studentId 
AND duration_id = 1 
AND Cast(receipt_date AS DATE) = Cast(@date AS DATE) 
AND type_id = @typeid 
AND receipt_code = @receiptCode 
AND receipt_cancel = 0)
```

Comment: This is quite complex, and we have no idea what your data looks like. Please [edit] your question to provide a proper [mre]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: This looks like SQL Server, not MySQL. The solution is to use the correct types, not strings and casting. Use the `date` type for date variables and fields. Use `numeric(p,s)` for amounts. Don't convert to strings until you have to display the data

Comment: PS you gain nothing by using `money` either

Answer (score 0):

First, `select` is not needed for this.  And I prefer `COALESCE()` to `ISNULL()` (`COALESCE()` is standard SQL).

```
@mainamount = coalesce(format(cast(sum(receipt_amount) as money), 'N', 'en-in'), 0)
```

The problem is that the `0` specifies that the return type is a *number*.  When there is a type conflict, the more restrictive type is usually chosen -- that is, strings are converted to numbers and dates, when one has to be chosen.

But the `FORMAT()` is returning a string.  You can fix this just by have the alternative value be a string:

```
@mainamount = coalesce(format(cast(sum(receipt_amount) as money), 'N', 'en-in'), '0')
```